# Getting Issue in Generative AI (Gemini) Android App release Build

Tags: android, kotlin, google-gemini

I am working on the Gemini API Chat app. In debug APR app is running fine but in
release build it gives an exception  **generativeai.type.InvalidStateException**.

I can't find any documentation for that. Please try to help me out.
Here is the code with HiltModule and ViewModel.

Also, I won't get any pro-guard rules fot that.

`GeminiModule.kt`

```
 @Module
 @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
 object GeminiModule {
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideGemini(): GenerativeModel {
    val harassmentSafety =
        SafetySetting(HarmCategory.HARASSMENT, BlockThreshold.ONLY_HIGH)

    val hateSpeechSafety =
        SafetySetting(HarmCategory.HATE_SPEECH, BlockThreshold.MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE)
    val config = generationConfig {
        stopSequences = listOf(
            "fuck",
            "sex",
        )
        temperature = 0.9f
        topK = 16
        topP = 0.1f
    }
    return GenerativeModel(
        modelName = "gemini-pro",
        apiKey = BuildConfig.apiKey,
        generationConfig = config,
        safetySettings = listOf(
            harassmentSafety, hateSpeechSafety
        )
    )
}
```

}

And ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ChatViewModel @Inject constructor(
         private val generativeModel: GenerativeModel,
         private val case: ChatUseCases,
         private val mapper: ChatMessageToModelMapper
) : ViewModel() {

private var chat: Chat? = null

private val _uiState: MutableState<ChatUiState> =
    mutableStateOf(ChatUiState())
val uiState: State<ChatUiState> = _uiState

private val _isLoading = mutableStateOf<Boolean>(false)
val isLoading: State<Boolean> get() = _isLoading
private var job: Job? = null

init {
    getChat()
}

private fun getChat() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val history = mapper.mapFromEntityList(case.getAllChat.invoke()).toContent()
    chat = generativeModel.startChat(history)
    _uiState.value = ChatUiState(
        chat?.history?.map { content ->
            // Map the initial messages
            ChatMessage(
                text = content.parts.first().asTextOrNull() ?: "",
                participant = if (content.role == "user") Participant.USER else 
              Participant.MODEL,
            )
               } ?: emptyList()
    )
}


fun cancelJob() {
    try {
        _isLoading.value = false
        job?.cancel()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAGS.BIT_ERROR.name, "cancelJob: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
}

fun sendMessage(userMessage: String) {
    // Add a pending message
    val userInput = ChatMessage(
        text = userMessage, participant = Participant.USER,
    )
    _isLoading.value = true
    _uiState.value.addMessage(
        userInput
    )
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = chat!!.sendMessage(userMessage)
            _isLoading.value = false
            response.text?.let { modelResponse ->
                val modelRes = ChatMessage(
                    text = modelResponse, participant = Participant.MODEL
                )
                mapper.mapToEntityList(
                    listOf(
                        _uiState.value.getLastMessage()!!
                            .copy(
                                linkedId = modelRes.id
                            ),
                        modelRes.copy(
                            linkedId = _uiState.value.getLastMessage()!!.id
                        )
                    )
                ).forEach {
                    case.insertChat.invoke(it)
                }
                _uiState.value.addMessage(
                    modelRes
                )
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("AAA", "sendMessage: $e")
            if (e is PromptBlockedException) {
                _uiState.value.addMessage(
                    ChatMessage(
                        text = "The input you provided contains offensive language, which goes against our community guidelines " +
                                "and standards. Please refrain from using inappropriate language and ensure that your input is " +
                                "respectful and adheres to our guidelines. If you have any questions or concerns, feel free " +
                                "to contact our support team.",
                        participant = Participant.ERROR
                    )
                )
                return@launch
            }
            _uiState.value.addMessage(
                ChatMessage(
                    text = e.localizedMessage ?: "Unknown error",
                    participant = Participant.ERROR
                )
            )
        } finally {
            _isLoading.value = false
            job = null
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the stacktrace of the exception?